# .NET - What's the point of the JsonNode GetPath() method?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json, .net-7.0

I'm using the `System.Text.Json` package to work with/manipulate JSON and I've got a niche scenario where I can potentially reuse a method if I can provide it with a path to access the value of a node.

I noticed the `JsonNode` class has a `GetPath()` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.getpath?view=net-7.0) which, as you'd expect, returns the path of the targeted node.

However, it looks like you can't use this output in reverse, meaning once you know the path you can't use it to access the value of a node.

For example, say my JSON looked like this:

```
{
    "cakes": {
        "cheese": "cake"
    }
}
```

Calling `node["cakes"]["cheese"]` will result in `"cake"`.

Whilst calling `node["cakes"]["cheese"].GetPath()` will return `"$.cakes.cheese"`, the path to that `"cake"` value.

However, calling `node["$.cakes.cheese"]` just returns `null` where you'd expect it to return `"cake"`.

Am I being a dumbass and using this incorrectly?

Or is the `JsonNode` class simply not intended to work this way, if so what's the point of the `GetPath` method?

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve data via json path?

Comment: You're not missing anything -- `System.Text.Json` is. The feature request for it is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31068) (3+ years and counting).

Comment: Some alternatives in the meanwhile we are waiting for Microsoft: https://github.com/azambrano/JsonDocumentPath, https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything, https://github.com/danielaparker/JsonCons.Net

Answer (score 5):

Using the path is currently (.NET 7) not supported. It might be supported in a later version.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft):

> The JsonDocument DOM doesn't support querying by using JSON Path.
>
> In a JsonNode DOM, each JsonNode instance has a GetPath method that
> returns a path to that node. But there is no built-in API to handle
> queries based on JSON Path query strings.

If you need very flexible Json support, use the `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget package.